# Having Trouble Centering Website

Tags: css, css-float

I've purchased a script not too long ago, it's a little old. Anyway, the page is aligned left. I don't know much about programming. I searched Google, YouTube, and Stack Overflow to find an answer to my simple question, but no luck. I'm pretty sure it will need to be centered with a (div) tag but the details... I get lost. Please take a look help please.

```
a, a:visited, a:active {
color: #9b7e5b;
}
a.toplink, a.toplink:hover, a.toplink:visited, a.toplink:active {
color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.forCopyright {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
    COLOR: #FFFFFF; 
text-align: center;
background-color: #B57C37;
}
a.forCopyright {
text-decoration: underline;
}
body, td, .forTexts {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #000000;
}
a.menutxt, a.menutxt:hover, a.menutxt:visited, a.menutxt:active {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
color: #9b7e5b;
}
.menutxt {
PADDING-RIGHT: 2px;
    PADDING-LEFT: 5px;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 10px;
color: #9b7e5b;
}
.infotxt {
PADDING-RIGHT: 5px;
    PADDING-LEFT: 5px;
font-size: 10px;
}
th {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
color: #000000;
}
.title {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-image: url("images/bg.jpg");
font-size: 12px;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;

}
.inpts {
BORDER-RIGHT: #9b7e5b 1px solid; 
    BORDER-TOP: #9b7e5b 1px solid; 
    FONT-SIZE: 10px; 
    BORDER-LEFT: #9b7e5b 1px solid; 
    COLOR: #000000; 
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #9b7e5b 1px solid; 
    FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff
}
.sbmt {
BORDER-RIGHT: #9b7e5b 1px solid; 
    BORDER-TOP: #9b7e5b 1px solid; 
    FONT-SIZE: 10px; 
    BORDER-LEFT: #9b7e5b 1px solid; 
    COLOR: #000000; 
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #9b7e5b 1px solid; 
    FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #DEC8AD; 
}
a.hlp, a.hlp:active, a.hlp:visited, a.hlp:hover {
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 12px;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: help;
}
.line {
background-color: #B57C37;
}
.bgcolorleft {
background-color: white;
}
.bgcolormain {
background-color: white;
}
.bgcolorright {
background-color: white;
}
div.framebody {
text-align: center;
}
div.main {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto; 
 }
td.inheader {
background-image: url("images/bg.jpg"); 
background-color: white;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center; 
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
td.item {
background-color: E2B176;   
text-align: center; 

}
h3 {
COLOR: #664422; 
    FONT-FAMILY: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}
.calendartable {
background-color: #664422;
text-align: center;
}
.calendartablebg {
background-color: white;
}
.calendarweek {
background-color: #664422;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: center;

}
td.gray {
    color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Please provide your html code as well, or some link to your site, or a  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for us to help

Comment: You could try enclosing your html in `<center>` tags.

Comment: Without any HTML code we can only guess... however if you need to center something, put a `<div></div>` around it and apply `text-align: center;` to that div.

Comment: ^ don't use the <center> tag it's deprecated

Comment: What script? Like to smoke pot legally?

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a container div to wrap around your entire body. Like so:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
  ...
  ...Your Website Code...
  ...
  </div> <!-- end container -->
</body>
```

Then in your css:

```
.container {
  width: 950px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure without HTML, but I would guess you need a width on div.main:

```
div.main {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  width: 960px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the "Main" div is what you want to center. You need to define width in there.

```
div.main {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto; 
width:90%;
 }
```

or

```
div.main {
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto; 
width:1000px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align the content of the div to the center, use CSS property:

```
text-align:center;
```

if you want to align the container div to the center, then give it the width and use CSS property margin:0 auto;

```
div{width:1000px;margin:0 auto;}
```

Finally if nothing is working for you use `positon:relative;` for parent and then the child element should have a `position:absolute;top:XXpx; left:XXpx;`

Please make sure you read some basic [**CSS here**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp). but also don't ignore this [**link**](http://w3fools.com/) as well